# multiple get request using asyncio and aiohttp with timeout period

Tags: asynchronous, python-3.6, python-asyncio, aiohttp

**Problem-** I am trying to make multiple get requests to different urls using asyncio, async_timeout and aiohttp. I just want to do rest processing either after completed all get request or after timeout period elapses whichever happens first. If all tasks doesn't complete within specified _DEFAULT_TIME_OUT period then whatever get request completed proceed with them only.

In below code snippet I am always waiting for _DEFAULT_TIME_OUT period even though all my tasks has been completed. How to explicitly resolve the timeout.

```
async def get(self, session, url, attributes):
        timeout_period = self._DEFAULT_TIME_OUT)
        try:
            with async_timeout.timeout(timeout_period) as timeout:
                async with session.get(url) as response:
                    self.urls[url] = await response.content.read()
                    response.release()
                print("---{}---".format(url))
                raise asyncio.TimeoutError()
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            pass

async def http_request(self, even_loop):
    tasks = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=even_loop) as session:
        for url in all_urls:
            tasks.append(self.get(session, url, attributes))
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        print("Do something else")
```

Answer (score 1):

This example shows how to work with `async_timeout` and get info about tasks:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import async_timeout


async def get(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            return await response.json()


async def main():
    timeout = 3.5

    tasks = [
        asyncio.create_task(get(f'http://httpbin.org/delay/{delay}'))
        for delay
        in range(1, 6)
    ]

    try:
        with async_timeout.timeout(timeout):
            await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        pass
    finally:
        for i, task in enumerate(tasks):
            if task.done() and not task.cancelled():
                print(f'Task is finished: {task.result()["url"]}.')
            else:
                print(f'Task hasn\'t been finished.')


asyncio.run(main())
```

**Result:**

```
Task is finished: http://httpbin.org/delay/1.
Task is finished: http://httpbin.org/delay/2.
Task is finished: http://httpbin.org/delay/3.
Task hasn't been finished.
Task hasn't been finished.
```

---

You can play with `timeout` and `delay` variables to see that everything work as expected:

```
timeout = 10

tasks = [
    asyncio.create_task(get(f'http://httpbin.org/delay/{delay}'))
    for delay
    in (1, 1, 1)
]
```

Will be finished shortly after 1 sec. with all tasks completed.